# Strange C++ rule for member function pointers?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, pointer-to-member

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Error with address of parenthesized member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134197/error-with-address-of-parenthesized-member-function)

In [this recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134197/function-pointers/7134218#7134218) the OP ran into a strange provision of the C++ language that makes it illegal to take the address of a member function if that member function name is parenthesized.  For example, this code is illegal:

```
struct X {
    void foo();
};

int main() {
    void (X::* ptr)();
    ptr = &(X::foo);   // Illegal; must be &X::foo
}
```

I looked this up and found that it's due to §5.3.1/3 of the C++ ISO spec, which reads

> A pointer to member is only formed when an explicit & is used and its operand is a qualified-id not enclosed in parentheses [...]

Does anyone have any idea why the spec has this rule?  It's specific to pointers-to-member, so I would suspect that there is some grammatical ambiguity that this resolves, but I honestly haven't the faintest idea what it might be.

Comment: @Hans: Not a duplicate.  OP is actually the highest-rated answer to that question, which asked _what_ the problem was.  This question is asking _why_.

Comment: @Troubadour: the WHY of something is different from the WHAT and HOW. for example, the what-question "what kind of trousers do Donald Duck wear?" has the answer "he's stark naked on lower part of body", but if you ask the why-question "why is Donald Duck stark naked on lower part of body", then it's a different answer, namely "he's a DUCK". To put it to a point, if you ask "what kind of trousers do Donald Duck wear", then it's **not** a valid answer to say "he's a DUCK". So as you can see, 2 diff q with 2 diff a. Cheers,

Comment: @Troubador- I did not intend for this to be a duplicate of your question.  My interpretation of your question was "what is the root cause of this problem" rather than "why is C++ structured this way," so I asked this question to get an answer to the latter question.  I apologize if I misread your initial question and repeated it here.

Comment: The original question **was** why. templatetypedef seems to have misinterpreted it as "what", which was silly, because the original question was "What is the reason behind not allowing parentheses while taking the address of a non-static member function?" This is very much a dupe.

Comment: Yep, this is a duplicate question.

Comment: @templatetypedef: It wasn't Troubador's question. Troubador has no questions.

Comment: "_Does anyone have any idea why the spec has this rule?_" Why wouldn't it? It's just syntax, so it's arbitrary.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is just a personal opinion.
If `&(qualified-id)` is allowed as `&(unary-expression)`,
qualified-id has to be an expression, and an expression is expected to have a type
(even if it is incomplete).
However, C++ didn't have a type which denotes a member, had only
a pointer to member.
For example, the following code cannot be compiled.

```
struct A { int i; };

template< class T > void f( T* );

int main() {
  (void) typeid( A::i );
  f( &A::i );
}
```

In order to make `&(qualified-id)` be valid, the compiler has to hold
a member type internally.
However, if we abandon `&(qualified-id)` notation, the compiler doesn't need
to handle member type.
As member type was always handled in the form of a pointer to it,
I guess the standard gave priority to simplify the compiler's type
system a little.

Comment: +1 i think you're right. :-)

Comment: @AlfP.Steinbach: Wow! That's really encouraging :-D

Comment: Awesome!  This seems like exactly the right answer.  Thank you so much for posting this!

Comment: @templatetypedef: Oh, not at all! Glad the answer helped :-)

Comment: Remember you can say `sizeof A::i` or `sizeof(A::i + 42)` in C++11. And you can call a non-static function with parenthesis wrapping the name: `struct A { void f() { } void g() { (f)(); } };` (`f` has type `void()` here).

Comment: @JohannesSchaub: Thank you for pointing out!
In addition to what you commented,
new standard seems to allow type-id like `int()const`.
This looks like a non-member function type, but has cv-qualifier for `this`.
If I were asked like so `This denotes a member (function) type, not a pointer
to member type, right?`, I couldn't answer well.
As I'm not so familiar with C++0x(11?), I wrote the answer with the past
tense form.

Answer (score 5):

Imagine this code:

```
struct B { int data; };
struct C { int data; };

struct A : B, C {
  void f() {
    // error: converting "int B::*" to "int*" ?
    int *bData = &B::data;

    // OK: a normal pointer
    int *bData = &(B::data);
  }
};
```

Without the trick with the parentheses, you would not be able to take a pointer directly to B's data member (you would need base-class casts and games with `this` - not nice).

---

From the ARM:

> Note that the address-of operator must be explicitly used to get a pointer to member; there is no implicit conversion ... Had there been, we would have an ambiguity in the context of a member function ... For example,
>
> ```
> void B::f() {
>     int B::* p = &B::i; // OK
>     p = B::i; // error: B::i is an int
>     p = &i; // error: '&i'means '&this->i' which is an 'int*'
>
>     int *q = &i; // OK
>     q = B::i; // error: 'B::i is an int
>     q = &B::i; // error: '&B::i' is an 'int B::*'
> }
> ```

The IS just kept this pre-Standard concept and explicitly mentioned that parentheses make it so that you don't get a pointer to member.