# What are the subtle differences between methods and free functions?

Tags: c++, function, methods, implementation

As I understand it, methods are really just functions with an implicit extra parameter (the `this` pointer), and static methods are the pretty much the same as free functions.

But there seem to be some differences between methods and functions; for example, when passing a function as an argument, why does the reference operator `&` have to be used on methods, but not on free functions?

```
foobar(&MyClass::method);
goobar(freefunction);
```

What other subtle technical differences are there between methods and free functions?

Comment: I could copy and paste the C++ FAQ but I will just link [it](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error with address of parenthesized member function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134197/error-with-address-of-parenthesized-member-function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In:

`foobar(&MyClass::method);`

... `&` is not the "reference operator" but is the address-of operator.  It takes the address of its operand.

You actually do still "have to" take the address of a free function in code such as (although implicit conversions are available):

```
goobar(freefunction);
```

There are implicit conversions available which will cause an expression such as `Foo` to decay in to a pointer, but I have had much difficulty in getting GCC to accept such code error- and warning-free, in cases where MSVC has no problems.

Aside from this, there are two main differences between free functions and non-static member functions:

1. Non-`static` member functions operate on an instance of a class, and there is a `this` pointer which points to the class itself.
2. The syntax for creating and calling through a pointer-to-free-function is different than that for a pointer-to-member-function.

In the case of the free function, the syntax is trivial(ish):

```
void foo();  // Function declaration
void(*f)();  // Declaration of pointer-to-function-returning-void-and-taking-no-parameters
```

But in the case of a pointer to a member function, the syntax is much trickier:

```
struct Bar
{
  void DoIt()
  {
  }
  void DoThat(int n)
  {
    n;
  }
};


void(Bar::*thatfn)(int);    // declares a pointer-to-member-function taking int returning nothing
thatfn = &Bar::DoThat;      // initializes pointer to point to DoThat(int)
(bar.*thatfn)(42);          // call the function
```

Comment: "but many compilers are lax on this." - wrong, the standard specifically states that you do not need to, as free functions decay into pointers at the drop of a hat.

Comment: @Xeo:  I've had much difficulty with implicit decomposition under Linux, whereas MSVC has no such issues.

Comment: @Xeo:  Regardless, I've edited my words to be less offensive to people focused on the leaves of the tree. ;)

Comment: Well, `MSVC 1 : 0 GCC` in that case. :P

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because of (§5.3.1/3) which says,

> **A pointer to member is only formed when an explicit & is used and its operand is a qualified-id not enclosed in parentheses.**

and then it goes on to explain this as:

> [Note: that is, the expression &(qualified-id), where the qualified-id is enclosed in parentheses, does not form an expression of type “pointer to member.” Neither does qualified-id, because there is no implicit conversion from a qualified-id for a nonstatic member function to the type “pointer to member function” as there is from an lvalue of function type to the type “pointer to function” (4.3). Nor is &unqualified-id a pointer to member, even within the scope of the unqualified-id’s class. ]

---

I just got two interesting topics discussing this, especially @Johannes's answer is a nice read here:

- [Error with address of parenthesized member function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7138582/415784)

and this one as well:

- [Strange C++ rule for member function pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134261/strange-c-rule-for-member-function-pointers)

Which also means this topic should be voted close, for it seems to be a duplicate.

Comment: I disagree about this question being a dupe of those questions, see here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109993/guidelines-for-closing-questions-as-exact-duplicate