# C++ Function Pointers as class member

Tags: c++, function-pointers

Well,

I typedef function pointer as :

```
typedef string(*t_arr[5])();
```

and then i create function in class as :

```
void initStringFunctionPointer(t_arr t_err);
```

and then i declared as :

```
void Register::initStringFunctionPointer(t_arr t_err)
{
    t_err[0] = &getName;
    t_err[1] = &getSurname;
    t_err[2] = &getUsername;
    t_err[3] = &getPassword;
    t_err[4] = &getEmail;
}
```

but all of lines gives this error :

```
C:\Qt Projects\base\ClassProject_tmp\goinlib.cpp:20: error: ISO C++ forbids taking the address of an unqualified or parenthesized non-static member function to form a pointer to member function.  Say '&Register::getName' [-fpermissive]
     t_err[0] = &getName;
                 ^
```

I don't know what to do, Any ideas ?

Edit :

It worked, static or doing type is succeed, thank you.

Comment: Your functions need to be static or you need to use member function pointers.

Comment: What are these functions?

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134197/error-with-address-of-parenthesized-member-function

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth in same cpp with void one

Comment: Perhaps try to change your `&getName;` stuff to `&Register::getName`. This worked in the duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134197/error-with-address-of-parenthesized-member-function

Answer (score 0):

It tells you right in the error message:

```
Say '&Register::getName'
```

Once you do this you will probably discover that it's illegal anyway because you can't store a pointer-to-member-function in a regular function pointer.  You'll need to change your typedef therefore, or else make `getName()` and the rest static.  To change the typedef, try this:

```
typedef string(Register::*t_arr[5])();
```

Hopefully that's right, the array thing makes me a little uncertain; you might consider keeping the array part out of the basic typedef and adding it on elsewhere (on a second typedef or at the place of use).

Comment: I already tried that,when i do that it gives me ' C:\Qt Projects\base\ClassProject_tmp\goinlib.cpp:20: error: cannot convert 'std::string (Register::*)() {aka std::basic_string<char> (Register::*)()}' to 'std::string (*)() {aka std::basic_string<char> (*)()}' in assignment
     t_err[0] = &Register::getName;
              ^'

Comment: @SashaValentine Try what I said in my latest comment.

Comment: @SashaValentine you didn't change your definition of `t_arr`

Comment: @MAttMcNabb actually i figured it out that but, i didnt figure out how to use that type in main function.I mean i want to use it like in for loop t_arr[i]();

Comment: `t_arr` is a typedef , `t_arr[i]` makes no sense. in any case, update your question to clarify what you are asking. Also if you change it to MCVE format then it will be easier to answer

Comment: i typedefed : typedef string(Register::*t_arr[5])(); and initalized   in function like : t_err[0] = &Register::getName; im doing in main function t_arr t_vec and tried that 't_vec[i]()'