# Why does taking a member function pointer value requires class name qualification even from inside of the class?

Tags: c++, methods, function-pointers, dereference, pointer-to-member

When returning a member function pointer to a class within one of that class's member functions I still have to specify the class. I cannot simply take the address. For example, [this code works fine](http://ideone.com/auaGLm):

```
class Foo {
public:
    void func(int param) { cout << param << endl; }
    void (Foo::*getPointer())(int) { return &Foo::func; }
};
```

But if in `getPointer` I try to simply do: `return &func` I get this error:

> prog.cpp: In member function '`void (Foo::* Foo::getPointer())(int)`':
>   prog.cpp:8:43: error: ISO C++ forbids taking the address of an unqualified or parenthesized non-static member function to form a pointer to member function.  Say '`&Foo::func`' [-fpermissive]
>     `void (Foo::*getPointer())(int) { return &func; }`

Why must I specify the class when that's the context that I am within?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Scope obviously. If there is a non-member variable with the same name as the class variable I don't have to specify the class.

Comment: Ah I misunderstood your question, you asking about the need for `Foo::` in `&Foo::func`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yeah, it's driving me batty why the compiler can't figure this out. I don't have to specify for static functions, member variables, when I call functions, or even taking the address of a member variable; but for some reason if I want the address of a function I must specify.

Comment: Beacuse the standard says so. If you think it's illogical then what do you think about the ability to assign a `double` to a `std::string` variable?

Comment: @6502 Ummm... What are you saying here? That by questioning why the standard requires this I am asking for us to just throw out strong typing? The gcc error states that: "ISO C++ forbids" it, I want to know why. What potential confusion is avoided by requiring the class name?

Comment: Did you actually try to assign a `double` to an `std::string` variable? It's legal... (welcome to hell ;-) )

Comment: @JonathanMee - The usual explanation is that no one has found it useful enough to bother writing a proposal for a language change. Compare this to the much more common `for`-statement that has gotten a shorter version `for (auto x : v) {}` because some people got tired of writing out the longer form, and presented a paper to the committee.

Comment: @6502 This doesn't work `double fp = 42; string str = fp;` I'm not sure what you're saying. Can you show me somecompiling code in http://www.ideone.com

Comment: @BoPersson If that's really the best we have for an answer I suppose it wouldn't hurt to write it up. I was just hoping to learn some black magic that this would have otherwise inhibited...

Comment: @JonathanMee http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a077e7768a68756e it converts double -> int -> char.

Comment: @Jonathan Mee:  double fp = 42; string str = fp;    ->   change this to: double fp = 42; string str ; str = fp;    it works.... constructor forbids it in the first case i guess.

Comment: @Andrew You're just using [the `char` assignment operator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator=/) here. You've implicitly done `string str = static_cast<char>(fp);`

Comment: @JonathanMee I know. It's just a sequence of implicit conversions. Nothing magical. But still somewhat undesirable.

Comment: @JonathanMee: not every `=` operator in C++ is an assignment. I said you can **assign** a `double` to an `std::string` variable, not that you can initialize an `std::string` instance with a `double`. Anyway the point was just that if you assume that C++ is always logical you're not going to get very far... much of C++ rules are because of accidents, history (backward compatibility) or just plain committee effect.

Comment: @6052 I don't know that [I assume everything is logical](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29967202/why-cant-i-define-a-function-inside-another-function), but I do assume that there is a reason for everything. C++ is a mature language, there isn't much, if anything, that's in the language "just cause someone felt like it."

Comment: @JonathanMee: unfortunately the "just cause someone felt like it" is, sometimes, the correct answer. Not always of course, and not even in the majority of the cases. But it happens.

Comment: Note that for *data members*, there's a difference between `&my_class::data_m` and `&data_m`. It seems more consistent to require `&my_class::mem_fun` for member functions.

Comment: @dyp Interesting. Is taking the `&my_class::data_m` giving me an offset rather than a physical address? It seems like it is? Perhaps that's the point of specifying the namespace?

Comment: @dyp was that you who made a comment about D&E a little while ago and then removed it?

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Yes, I misunderstood what the ARM was saying. I thought it was referring to an ambiguity when using *pointers to member functions*, but it says there's an ambiguity *within (the context of) a member function*. (Btw I'd also love to have a digital copy of D&E, my copy on dead tree is of very bad printing quality and already in bad shape.)

Comment: @JonathanMee Be careful when talking about obtuse details of language syntax.  `&my_class::data_m` does not specify any namespace.  `my_class` is the name of a class, not a namespace, and a class is *not* a namespace.  Similarly, `&my_class::data_m` is not the offset of `data_m` within `my_class`, it is a member variable pointer; a member variable pointer can (sometimes/often) be implemented as an offset, but you *should avoid confusing the map for the territory*: it is not an offset, that is just how it can be implemented (usually).

Comment: @Yakk That's actually a really valuable comment. This question seems to necessitate a "territorial" answer, rather than a "map" answer. I was thinking that a follow-up question would probably be in order to clarify that, but I haven't taken the time to completely formulate it in my mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pointers and pointer to members are distinct types, we can see that from section the draft C++ standard section `3.9.2` [basic.compound] which includes a compound type for pointer as well as *pointer to non-static class member* and notes:

> Static class members are objects or functions, and pointers to them
>   are ordinary pointers to objects or functions

This issue with this is I think well described in [this quote in an answer from Johannes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7138582/1708801) from the [Annotated C++ Reference Manual(*ARM*)](http://www.stroustrup.com/arm.html):

> Note that the address-of operator must be explicitly used to get a
>   pointer to member; there is no implicit conversion ... Had there been,
>   we would have an ambiguity in the context of a member function ... For
>   example,
>
> ```
> void B::f() {
>     int B::* p = &B::i;   // ok
>     p = B::i;         // error: B::i is an int
>     p = &i;           // error: '&i'means '&this->i'
>                       // which is an 'int*'
>
>     int *q = &i;      // ok
>     q = B::i;         // error: 'B::i is an int
>     q = &B::i;        // error: '&B::i' is an 'int B::*'
> }
> ```

In particular these lines:

```
int B::* p = &B::i; // OK
```

and:

```
p = &i; // error: '&i'means '&this->i' which is an 'int*'
```

demonstrate the difference between the qualified and the unqualified name.

Comment: I guess I need to pick up a copy of ARM to go next to my D&E, you can't buy a pdf of either :-(

Comment: I think I got it looking at your answer in combination with [dyp's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32842429/why-does-taking-a-member-function-pointer-value-requires-class-name-qualificatio/32845696#comment53523542_32842429). When I do `&B::` I'm getting the offset not the absolute address. I guess I'm to understand that all methods are called by offset, *not* actual address?

Comment: @JonathanMee that is one possible implementation, reading [Pointers to member functions are very strange animals](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/02/09/70002.aspx) should be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

(...there was a wrong answer...)

It looks more strange in the following context:

```
class Foo {
public:
    virtual void func(int param) { cout << param << endl; }
    void call(int x) { Foo::func(x); }
    void (Foo::*getPointer())(int) { return &Foo::func; }
};

class Bar : public Foo {
public:
    void func(int param) override { cout << "Hello world!" << endl; }
};


int main() {

    Foo *a = new Bar();
    auto p = a->getPointer();
    (a->*p)(4);
    a->call(4);

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

> Hello world
>   4

Calling `Foo::func` is a call of `func` in `Foo` class while calling `&Foo::func` is a virtual call.

Comment: Thank you so much. It all makes sense now.

Comment: This is wrong. A non-static member function address is not a pointer and requires a `this` to be used so it doesn't have to resolve to "an address" at compile time. Moreover if `mp` is pointing to `Foo::func` and you call it on a `Bar` instance then `Bar::func` version will be called.

Comment: @6502 Arg! You're shooting down the only reasonable explanation I've heard!

Comment: It becomes less logical